# Using EditorFor<> to render a drop-down list

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper, editorfor

So far we can use Html.EditorFor() to dynamically render the appropriate template for a datatype - e.g. string, int, or a custom type, say 'Address'.

Now I want to use EditorFor() to render a 'Parent' field. I want a drop-down containing every row, and the user picks a parent from this drop-down.

The 'Parent' template has access to the 'ParentID', but what about the names and ID's of rows, to populate the list-box with?

Where should these come from?

I could put data-access logic in the template, but that would be violating the separation of concerns.

I could create an HtmlHelper that renders the list, but wouldn't this also break separation of concerns, since HtmlHelpers should only do UI stuff, not data access?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a MVVM approach, maybe?  Your ViewModel would contain all the data you need to render the dropdown, as well as an "edit" model to store the user's input upon a POST, which would just be an ID number in this case, I guess.